# Eliminar archivos desde el controlador

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

Estoy usando laravel 6

Tengo 2 tablas:

**Tabla 1:** id, descripción.

**Tabla 2:** id, tabla1_id, file, file2

la tabla1 tiene la relacion de hasMany

la tabla2 tiene relacion de belongsTo

Al eliminar la **tabla1** tambien se elimina la **tabla2**. Lo que quiero hacer es que al eliminar la **tabla1** se borre la **tabla2** junto a todos los archivos que tengo en el proyecto cuya ruta está en la base de datos en los campos **file**

si elimino por aparte un campo de la tabla2 se elimina junto al archivo con el siguiente codigo:

```
unlink(storage_path('app/public/'.$tabla2->file));
unlink(storage_path('app/public/'.$tabla2->file2));
```

Pero al intentar eliminar todo desde la tabla1 no me funciona, he intentado con esto:

```
public function destroy($id){
   $tabla1    = Tabla1::find($id);
   $tabla2    = Tabla2::all()->where('tabla1_id', $id);

   if(isset($tabla2->file)){
     unlink(storage_path('app/public/'.$tabla2->file));
   }
   if(isset($tabla2->file2)){
     unlink(storage_path('app/public/'.$tabla->file2));
   }

   $tabla1->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por una lado, la consulta la puedes hacer así, en vez de traer todas las filas y después filtrar la colección:

```
$tabla2 = Tabla2::where('tabla1_id', $id)->get();
```

Luego, para eliminar los archivos, te sugiero usar [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem).

Puedes declarar un array para ir guardando los nombres de los archivos que existan en el disco. Usando [`Storage::disk('public')`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) ya no tendrás que especificar la ruta con `storage_path('app/public/'. ...)`, pues es la ruta predeteminada de ese disco de `Storage`:

```
$array_de_archivos = [];

foreach($tabla2 as $fila) {
    if( Storage::disk('public')->exists($fila->file) ) 
        $array_de_archivos[] = $fila->file;
    if( Storage::disk('public')->exists($fila->file2) ) 
        $array_de_archivos[] = $fila->file2;
}
```

Una vez que tengas el array con todos los nombres de archivos existentes, puedes pasárselo directamente al método [`delete()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#deleting-files) de `Storage`:

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete($array_de_archivos);
```

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar registros podes usar

```
DB::table('table_name')->delete();
```

Y para hacer un truncate

```
DB::table('table_name')->truncate();
```

Comment: Considera que el OP no usa el facade db y en cambio si los modelos

Comment: la tabla si se elimina, lo que quiero es que se eliminen los archivos que tiene el campo